# Array.splice() insert element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My API returns an array:

```
[
  [
    "valueA",
    9.036124999999998
  ],
  [
    "valueB",
    49.4075
  ]
]
```

After my API call I am setting up the data for some reports:

```
try {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const reports = [
    {
      title: "Average Cost By Service",
      hAxisTitle: "Service Type",
      vAxisTitle: "Total Spend",
      data: data.reports.averageCostByService.splice(0,0,['columnA', 'columnB'])
    }
  ]
  this.setState({
    reports: reports,
    num_records: data.records_in_range
  })
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

but instead of inserting the element, I am seeing an empty array.

```
[]
```

`splice()` should modify my array by inserting the element into the zeroeth position...

Comment: `.splice()` will return an array containing the deleted elements, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value). As you're not deleting any you'll get an empty array. You can use `[['columnA', 'columnB'], ...data.reports.averageCostByService]` to keep this immutable

Comment: Call `data.reports.averageCostByService.splice(0,0,['columnA', 'columnB'])` BEFORE you set `const reports = [ ..., data: data... ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) doesn't return the transformed array. To achieve what you want, try this:

```
try {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const { reports: { averageCostByService }} = data;

  averageCostByService.splice(0,0,['columnA', 'columnB'])
  const reports = [
    {
      title: "Average Cost By Service",
      hAxisTitle: "Service Type",
      vAxisTitle: "Total Spend",
      data: averageCostByService
    }
  ]
  this.setState({
    reports: reports,
    num_records: data.records_in_range
  })
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: @Saji Rika thanks for the help.  I missed ```If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.``` in the return value section of the guide.  I guess adding an element without deleting any, I stupidly expected the return similar to other higher order array functions.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are expecting the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) call to return you the updated array, which it won't.

Try this using [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and you have your expected result.

```
const reports = [
  {
    title: "Average Cost By Service",
    hAxisTitle: "Service Type",
    vAxisTitle: "Total Spend",
    data: [['columnA', 'columnB']].concat(data.reports.averageCostByService)
  }
];
```

Alternatively, you could try prepending the value before the assignment, like this:

```
data.reports.averageCostByService.unshift(['columnA', 'columnB']);

const reports = [
  {
    title: "Average Cost By Service",
    hAxisTitle: "Service Type",
    vAxisTitle: "Total Spend",
    data: data.reports.averageCostByService
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) doesn't return the modified array, as others have pointed out. Another option is to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create the new array:

```js
data: [['columnA', 'columnB'], ...data.reports.averageCostByService],
```

Comment: The OP is trying to insert an array `['columnA', 'columnB']` into the array as a first element, you are flattening them up here; need to correct that.